# List<List<String>>からList<String>へ分割する方法

Tags: java

`List<List<String>>`から`List<String>`へ分割する方法がわかりません。

csvResultとして、`[["商品コード], [", "商品名], [", "金額], [", 数量, おすすめ], [, ドトールコーヒー, 500, 30, 1], [, エクシオール, 300, 50, 0], [, スタバもか, 400, 40, 1], [518, green, 444, 35, 0]]`のように今CSVファイルを読み込ませてListを取得しました。
今、 csvWriteControllerには

```
List<List<String>> csvResult = csvReading.read();

try {
    for(int i=0; i<csvResult.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(csvResult[i]);
    }
}
```

と記載したのですが、`csvResult[i]`が`List<List<String>>`型ではつかえないとエラーが出ました。
どのように書けばよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

csvResultは配列ではありませんので、[]というオペレーターはサポートしていません。
`csvResult[i]`を`csvResult.get(i)`に変更してください。
また、`System.out.println()`は`List<String>`を出力することはできませんので、
`csvResult.get(i)`に対して、`for`文で文字列を出力してください。

```
List<List<String>> csvResult = csvReading.read();

try {
    for(int i = 0; i < csvResult.size(); i++) {
        if (null != csvResult.get(i)) {
            for (int j = 0; j < csvResult.get(i).size(); j++) {
                System.out.println(csvResult.get(i).get(j));
            }
        }
    }
}
```